# Data can't be stored on mongodb from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a sample webpage in rubyonrails  which has two textbox and a button . When i enter some data in the text box and click the button no error appears . But the data is not stored in the data base . What is the mistake that i committed .

login.html.erb file :

```
<%= form_for @product, url:{action: "login"} do |f| %>
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from      being saved:</h2>

<ul>
<% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :username %><br>
<%= f.text_field :username %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %><br>
<%= f.text_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb file:

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do
get "sample/login"
root 'sample#login'
post 'sample/:id' => 'sample#login'
end
```

sample controller file :

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController
def login
@product=Logz.new
end
end
```

and the model class name Logz contains the necessary field names 
username and password . If there was any error i could manage . but it shows no errors.

Comment: Is @product a Logs model instance?

Comment: how do you know it's not saving the data in MongoDB?

Comment: @CWitty .. yes it is..

Comment: @AsyaKamsky .. because when i insert it shows no error and i check the mongo shell . there is no datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem once. I dont know how its happened . but i just changed the content in database.yml

```
localhost:yourdb_development
```

into

```
127.0.0.1:ypurdb_development
```

and i got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the data to method login, but it just instantiate a new Product and it aren't receiving any attributes... and even if received... it are not saving the Product at all, so does not persist the data.

Try add a method create... that will be responsible for receive the data and save

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController

def create
  @product = Logz.new(params[:product])

  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to 'sample#login', notice: 'Data saved successfully' }
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'A wild error appeared'
  end 
end
```

After that, create the route to `post 'sample/create'` and change the action to where your form send the data...  `form_for @product, action: "create", method: 'post'`

Doing that... i will be possible to persist the data on your database...

PS:
You can use the content of that method inside your login method... but I dont recommend that... it is ugly and does not follos the conventions of rails.

I even recommend you to do a refactory... because it doesn't make sense access a SampleController in order to create a Product... that is persisted in an object called Logz...

The best practice is all follow the same name... LogzController, @logz, and finally your model Logz. and preferably your routes following the same pattern...

Another thing is, it would be nice to change your method login to a method call 'new' because that method you use to fill a new Logz... not to login...